# Call DLL from VBA in Excel (enum type)

Tags: vba, excel, dll, enums

I got this enumeration and this function from the DLL :

```
enum My_Enum {
    enum1 = 0,
    enum2  = !0,
};
typedef enum My_Enum My_Enum;

My_Enum myFunction(int arg);
```

Every time I try to call it from VBA Excel crashes. I know it probably mean types are wrong but I can't fix this.

This is my VBA code :

```
Declare Function dll_myFunction Lib "C:\link_to_my_dll.dll" _
        Alias "myFunction" (ByVal arg As Long) As Long

Private Sub Try_Calling()
    Dim myArg As Long
    myArg = 150
    dll_myFunction myArg
End Sub
```

Already tried to change type to be Integer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably VBA crashes because of mismatching calling convention?
I've made an example of DLL with Visual Studio 2015 and successfully called it from my Excel document.

Here is my DLL code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

enum NumSign {
  ns_undefined = 0,
  ns_plus,
  ns_minus,
};

__declspec(dllexport) NumSign __stdcall GetSign(int value) {
  if(value > 0)
    return ns_plus;
  if(value < 0)
    return ns_minus;
  return ns_undefined;
}
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Declare Function GetSign Lib "DLL_declaration.dll" _
(ByVal value As Long) As Long

Sub DLL_call()
    Dim myArg As Long
    Dim retVal As Long
    myArg = 150
    retVal = GetSign(3)
    MsgBox (retVal)
End Sub
```

Your mistake is that you haven't specified __stdcall in C++ code.
For me it works fine now.